# How do I handle (not fix!) a CORS exception in Ionic Framework?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, iis

We have an Angular/Ionic app installed on iPhone and Android. The app calls an API on our IIS web server. When the server is up, everything works well.

However, while we are deploying a new version of the API website, we would like our app to show a maintenance page. Currently, during the deployment, we create an app_offline.htm file in the API site's root folder, which is the usual way of taking a website offline and showing a maintenance page in IIS.

Unfortunately, this means the CORS preflight request from our Ionic app also returns a 503 http error code; I guess that IIS takes the whole site down. We are unable to handle this 503 error in the Angular/Ionic app on the phone, since the preflight request is triggered by the browser. We add custom headers to each request, which cannot be avoided. The net result is that the maintenance page is not displayed when the API site is down.

Is there a way to show a maintenance page in our Ionic/Angular app while the API site is being deployed? Perhaps by configuring IIS to allow preflight requests even when app_offline.htm is in place, somehow handling the 503 on the Ionic side, or even stopping the preflight OPTIONS request from the Ionic app?

NOTE: I am NOT asking how to configure my site to solve a CORS issue, that part is already in place. I want to handle an expected CORS error when it occurs in the app while the supporting API site is being deployed.

Comment: Have you considered a "heartbeat" api that can return a status code indicating the status of your API/Server? You could use an auth guard to determine a status and then route the app to the appropriate ionic page depending on the status code.

Comment: @leewhitbeck thanks for the suggestion! We did consider this, as there are some simple API calls that don't trigger a pre-flight, which we could use for the heartbeat call. We eventually decided against it, because we would need to call the heartbeat API before every actual API call in the app, reducing performance. I think it would work, but I'm hoping there is some way to handle the error on the actual API call.

Comment: You can create a static maintenance page. Then  rewrite the url of home page to maintenance page. Application still work and can accept CORS preflight request. Other requests redirect to maintenance page.

Comment: @BruceZhang how does that work with app_offline.htm? Or do you mean we deploy an empty website before deploying the new version?

Comment: It isnot work with app_offline.html. Url rewrite is used to redirect all requests to maintenance page but allow CORS preflight request.

Comment: I am assuming you handle general errors with some interceptor. if this is the case then when a error occurs you can then call the 'heartbeat' api as @leewhitbeck suggested, or just check if the 'app_offline.htm' is currently up. And then take the appropriate action ?

Comment: I agree with @Jayme. You can use the error handler or interceptor to look at the response codes and route accordingly.  This would mitigate the performance concern too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> For security reasons, specifics about what went wrong with a CORS request are not available to JavaScript code. All the code knows is that an error occurred. The only way to determine what specifically went wrong is to look at the browser's console for details.

You can find out more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors) at developer.mozilla.org

My suggestion is to handle any request errors like any other, inside of a interceptor.

You can then make use of the properties on the error object (like a status of 0) to decide if you should check if you are in maintenance mode, or you can just always check the mode when you get any errors.

To do this you can check if the `app_offline.htm` page is currently up or not with a web request,
or you can make use of a separate API to determine if you are currently in maintenance mode or not.

Then take the appropriate actions based on that response.

Comment: This is the solution we ended up using. Many thanks to all who contributed to the discussion!

Answer (score 0):

maybe discuss among you about 2 sites/api approach.
extra api to handle all requests (responds with the necessary headers and perhaps a maintenance message/status for the app to handle) when the real api is being updated.

following is an article about favoring 2 sites method. although the host is serving static content and not an api, similar pattern can be followed

https://www.vegait.rs/media-center/blog/offline-maintenance-mode-in-iis

Answer (score 0):

"We are unable to handle this 503 error in the Angular/Ionic app on the phone, since the preflight request is triggered by the browser." How are you unable to handle errors ?

All http.get requests have try/catch routines you can use. If data is not received from server, fallback  / navigate to another page, showing API server is down for maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to use an interceptor. If you detect an error code of 503 or any other error code, you can redirect the user to your app_offlane.htm page. It should look something like this:

```
export class AppInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

constructor(private router: Router) {}

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

return next.handle(request).pipe(tap(() => { },
            (err: any) => {
                if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {

                    // HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE = 503

                    if (err.status === HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE){
                        this.router.navigate([`app_offline.htm`]);
                    } else {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cors is not an ionic's rule, cors is a server rule whose allow or deny requests, this is a good behaviour.

You must add rules to your iis where allow or deny request based on origins,

In your server appication you should add to response headers cors instructions such as:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type"/>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS"/>
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

Check out your server application headers, pay attention on `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` if `*` wild card not work, try add ionic origin maybe http://localhost:8100